# Example of jQuery code next to react code (noob)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend

I haven't looked in to React much but can see that a lot of companies require it for a job with them. Having only ever used html/css over the past 12 years and js (jQuery mostly but also vanilla and es6) the past couple years. I was wondering if someone could show me an example of some simple code that you could use in jQuery and also in React.

In the next year I'm going hone in on React but would just like to see an example comparison of the two different libraries achieving the same result. As I don't understand fully what React does is this possible or do they both provide options to do entirely different things? Given that React is so sought after I'd imagine you can do the same things you can with jQuery, is it right to assume that?

Also I have read that jQuery manipulates the DOm and react uses a virtual DOM. Am I right in saying that this means jQuery will affect what exists in the html and Reacts purpose is to insert elements in to the DOM? If that's right, what's the advantage to doing this with react rather than using the append method with jQuery?

Having only looked in to JavaScript properly for the past year is this something I should already know? Is anything I have asked ridiculous/obvious? I just want to gain a better understanding and eventually build a career doing what I do for most of my spare time outside of work.

Thank you if you've read this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: Let's say there's an e-commerce site where a user clicks `Add to cart` button and a product gets added to their cart. The cart icon on the top navigation should show the number of items in cart.

Jquery code would look something like this:

```
var items_in_cart = 0;

$('#add-to-cart-button').on('click', function() {
    // first update the state variable
    items_in_cart++;

    // now update the DOM element
    $('#cart-items-icon').html(items_in_cart);
});
```

As you can see you are maintaining state **as well as** updating the DOM yourself.

But in React, all you'll need to do is just change the `items_in_cart` variable and React will automatically update the DOM.

This is a very simple example and doesn't really show the advantages of this approach. But if multiple components depend on a particular state, that's where React starts to shine. Like a complex form where certain fields get enabled and disabled depending on the value of a checkbox, or a single page application.